# Trying to install Steam on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: steam

Here is the error that I am getting when I try to install steam:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.6)
    unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

I am really stuck and have tried to install the dependencies with varying errors.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Still getting the same thing...

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: Here is what I get when I try to do that:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and give the link to [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then rerun the Steam installer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all very much for all the help on this! I now have steam working. Here are the steps that I took to get it running:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I did the install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y steam
```

Now Steam is running and I am well on my way to downloading my games and gaming on Linux!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y steam
```

(If you've installed Steam already, skip to next step)

Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf
```

Paste these two lines

```
/usr/lib32
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
```

save and exit

Run `sudo ldconfig`

and 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Run steam